# Get the argument names of an R function

Tags: r, function, expression, non-standard-evaluation

For an arbitrary function

```
f <- function(x, y = 3){
  z <- x + y
  z^2
}
```

I want to be able take the argument names of `f`

```
> argument_names(f)
[1] "x" "y"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Check out `?formals`

Comment: Awesome! Both work. Feel free to answer. I will accept the first.

Comment: help("args") or one of the functions linked there.

Comment: @landau Oh hey I know you. Small world.

Comment: Yeah @Dason, I remember you from grad school. How about that? Zheyuan Li declined his chance to claim the best answer. Want some easy points?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`formalArgs` and `formals` are two functions that would be useful in this case.  If you just want the parameter names then `formalArgs` will be more useful as it just gives the names and ignores any defaults.  `formals` gives a list as the output and provides the parameter name as the name of the element in the list and the default as the value of the element.

```
f <- function(x, y = 3){
  z <- x + y
  z^2
}

> formalArgs(f)
[1] "x" "y"
> formals(f)
$x


$y
[1] 3
```

My first inclination was to just suggest `formals` and if you just wanted the names of the parameters you could use names like `names(formals(f))`.  The `formalArgs` function just is a wrapper that does that for you so either way works.

Edit: Note that technically primitive functions don't have "formals" so this method will return NULL if used on primitives.  A way around that is to first wrap the function in `args` before passing to `formalArgs`.  This works regardless of it the function is primitive or not.

```
> # formalArgs will work for non-primitives but not primitives
> formalArgs(f)
[1] "x" "y"
> formalArgs(sum)
NULL
> # But wrapping the function in args first will work in either case
> formalArgs(args(f))
[1] "x" "y"
> formalArgs(args(sum))
[1] "..."   "na.rm"
```

Comment: @MichaelChirico Hmmm. Looks like anything that is just a wrapper to a .primitive call has the same issue.

Comment: yea I was trying to find all the one-argument functions in base and ran into this issue -- all the good ones are just primitive wrappers

Comment: @MichaelChirico I think I found a workaround. Technically `formalArgs` providing NULL for primitives isn't a bug. The help page for `formals` says "Only closures have formals, not primitive functions." which explains why this happens.  `args` itself returns a closure which is why the 'trick' gives us what we want.

Comment: Note that `formals()` also works for `f(x=1, y = a)` (`a` being an object like `a <- 3`). Then (for my use case) you can even do: `formals(f)$y == 'a'`.