# R get argument names from function call

Tags: r, function, arguments, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

I'd like to get  argument names from function call:

```
testFun <- function(x = 1:20, z = list(a = 1, b = 2)) x %>% sin %>% sum

getArgNames <- function(value) {
  # function should return all arguments names - in this case c("x", "z")

}
arg.names <- getArgNames(testFun())
```

And it is important to not to evaluate function before getting argument names. Any ideas?

Comment: It is not duplicate, because I want to extract argument names from evaluated function call, not from function name only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the same `formalArgs` suggested by @Akrun (and also in the almost duplicate [Get the argument names of an R function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640322/get-the-argument-names-of-an-r-function)):

```
getArgNames <- function(value) formalArgs(deparse(substitute(value)[[1]]))
```

`substitute(value)` quotes the input, to prevent immediate evaluation, `[[1]]` retrieves the function from the parsed input, `deparse` turns it into `character` (since `formalArgs` can take the function name as `character`).

```
getArgNames(testFun())

#[1] "x" "z"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `formalArgs`

```
formalArgs(testFun)
#[1] "x" "z"
```

If we need to pass the parameter as executable function

```
library(rlang)
getArgNames <- function(value) {
     v1 <- enquo(value)
     args <- formalArgs(get(gsub("[()]", "", quo_name(v1))))
     list(args, value)
     }

getArgNames(testFun())
#[[1]]
#[1] "x" "z"

#[[2]]
#[1] 0.9982219
```

Comment: Good idea, but `formalArgs` works on function name `formalArgs(testFun)`, not on evaluated function: `formalArgs(testFun())`.

Comment: @Taz Then maybe `getArgNames <- function(value) formalArgs(deparse(substitute(value)[[1]]))`

Comment: @akrun Do you mind if I turn my comment into a separate answer, since the syntax I use differs enough from yours?

Comment: @Aurèle  Sure you can do that