# Converting R function argument into a string

Tags: r, function

I have a function that looks like

```
my_function <- function(object)
{
  # code goes here
}
```

I'd like the function (among other things) to print the name of the argument (as passed to the function). So if my function call is:

```
xxx <- my_function(my_object)
```

then I'd like to know how to get the function to print out the string `"my_object"`.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I know of formalArgs, but formals apparently also works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640322/get-the-argument-names-of-an-r-function

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest next approach which is closer to what you want. For sure you could modify it to obtain other outputs:

```
#Function
my_function <- function(x)
{
  as.character(eval(parse(text=enquo(x)))[2])
}
#Apply
my_function(x = my_object)
```

Output:

```
[1] "my_object"
```

An improvement thanks to @MrFlick is next:

```
#Function
my_function <- function(x)
{
  rlang::as_label(rlang::enquo(x))
}
#Apply
my_function(x = my_object)
```

Which produces same output with a more elegant style in the function:

```
[1] "my_object"
```

Comment: @Alan Thanks to you!!! Great question! If you think this answer was helpful, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)

Comment: This is a very weird combination of rlang and base R. If you are going to use `rlang::enquo`, it would make more sense to use `rlang::as_label(enquo(x))` to get the name out. Otherwise the `deparse/substitute` is more idiomatic in base R.

Comment: @MrFlick I have added what you mentioned to the solution ! Thanks for your comment Dr. Flick!

Answer (score 6):

A more `R`-ish solution would be to use `substitute` (get substitute for `obj`) in combination with `deparse` (cast symbol to string):

```
my_function <- function(obj) {deparse(substitute(obj))}
```

General `R` metaprogramming rule: prefer `substitute`!

```
my_function(my_object)
## [1] "my_object"
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the entire call use `match.call` like this:

```
f <- function(x) { print(match.call()); x }
f(pi)
## f(x = pi)
## [1] 3.141593
```

IF it is desired to display the call just for debugging without modifying the function itself then use `trace`:

```
g <- function(x) x  # test function

trace(g)
g(pi)
## trace: g(pi)
## [1] 3.141593
```